# Let $f,g$ be differentiable functions such that $\int\limits_0^{f(x)}f(t)g(t)dt=g(f(x))$. Show that $g(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Let $f,g$ be differentiable functions such that $$\int\limits_0^{f(x)}f(t)g(t)dt=g(f(x))$$ Show that $g(0)=0$

I know it is done if $f(x)=0$ for some $x$, but I just have $$f(f(x))g(f(x))f'(x)=g'(f(x))f'(x)$$ by FTC, but then I dont know what to do.

Comment: This is not true in general (as Felice demonstrated below). I think you need to add the hypotesis that $0\in \text{Range}(f)$, but then as you say the problem becomes almost trivial.

Comment: Maybe it's enough $0\in\overline{Range(f)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, i don't understand. What about $f(t)=1$ and $g(t)=1$ for every $t$?
Maybe there are other hypothesis.

Comment: The problem is $g(0)=1$ and you don't need $g(0)=0$

Comment: I think it is a counterexample

Comment: oh, I see, but  the problem doesn't say more.

Comment: I don't see any other simple hp. I'll think about it.